# Example of $\det \rho(g)=\det \sigma(g)$ for all $g\in G$, but $\rho \not\simeq \sigma$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices, representation-theory

> Give an example of a group $G$ and two representations $\rho$ and $\sigma$ of $G$ such that $\det \rho(g)=\det \sigma(g)$ for all $g\in G$, but $\rho \not\simeq \sigma$.

At the moment but (unsuccessful) approach is trial and error in finding $2\times 2$ matrices with the same determinant. I have a hunch that $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a possible set of options. Is there a better way to approach this question, I feel there should be a more logical way? Somehow there should be a way of finding matrices that are no conjugate.

Comment: Any two representations of any finite nonabelian simple group would work, because all of the determinants would be $1$.

Comment: Here's a more specific example. Consider the symmetric group $S_n.$ Every $\pi\in S_n$ has a sign $\sigma(\pi) = \pm 1,$ and the map $\pi \mapsto \sigma(\pi)$ is a representation. Denote by $I_2$ the 2-by-2 identity matrix and consider the following representations of $S_n.$ $\alpha: \pi \mapsto I_2$ and $\beta: \pi \mapsto \sigma(\pi)I_2.$ Then we have $\forall \pi\in S_n:\det(\alpha(\pi)) = 1 = \det(\beta(\pi)),$ but $\alpha \not\simeq\beta$ (at least for $n>1$).

Comment: @DerekHolt could you explain your comment please. I am new to this area and it is not clear why your answer would work.

Comment: @jflipp I dont see why the determinants would be the same. Have you chosen $\beta$ as det =1? Moreover how do you know that the matrices are not conjugate? Is there a theorem in linear algebra I am missing?

Comment: To understand Derek's suggestion, you should use the fact that the kernel of the determinant map is a normal subgroup of the group $G$. Thus if a group is nonabelian and simple this means that the kernel is the whole group, i.e. that all of the determinants for **any** representation of $G$ are equal to $1$.

Comment: @NickGill where are the justifications for your first two sentences? I cannot find them in james & liebeck

Comment: You should (1) check that the determinant is a group homomorphism; then (2) use the fact that the kernel of a homomorphism is always normal. Now, by the simplicity of $G$, you can conclude that the kernel is $1$ or $G$. Then (3) use the first theorem of group isomorphisms and the fact that $G$ is abelian to rule out the possibility that the kernel equals $1$.

Comment: Fix a $\pi\in S_n.$ Then we have $\alpha(\pi) = I_2,$ the 2-by-2 identity matrix. Calculating the determinant gives $\det(\alpha(\pi)) = \det(I_2) = 1.$ Also, $\beta(\pi) = I_2$ or $\beta(\pi) = -I_2,$ depending on the value of $\sigma(\pi).$ We already noted that $\det(I_2) = 1.$ Also, $\det(-I_2) = (-1)^2\det(I_2) = 1.$ So we indeed have $\det(\alpha(\pi)) = 1 = \det(\beta(\pi)).$ Are you aware of the concept of the [sign of a permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation)? If you've never before worked with permutations, my example might not be so enlightening to you.

Comment: Regarding the equivalence of the representations $\alpha$ and $\beta.$ Let's work over $\mathbb C$ (or any other field of characteristic 0). Let's also assume that $n > 1.$ Then there is a $\rho\in S_n$ with $\sigma(\rho) = -1.$ Thus we have $\alpha(\rho) = I_2$ and $\beta(\rho) = -I_2.$ Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equivalent, i.e. there is an invertible 2-by-2 matrix $T$ such that $\forall \pi\in S_n: T\alpha(\pi)T^{-1} = \beta(\pi).$ Specifically for $\rho$ we get $-I_2 = \beta(\rho) = T\alpha(\rho)T^{-1} = TI_2T^{-1} = TT^{-1} = I_2.$ That's a contradiction, ...

Comment: ... since $-I_2 \neq I_2$ over $\mathbb C.$ So $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can't be equivalent.

Comment: @jflipp Why dont you put this as a solution? You wont get any points for great comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to @1234's suggestion, this answer is just a fleshing out of Derek's comment:

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite simple group. I claim that if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are any two complex representations of $G$, then they satisfy $\det(\rho(g))=1=\det(\sigma(g))$ for all $g\in G$, as required by the O.P.

Hint as to how to prove this: We consider the map $\det(L)\to \mathbb{C}$ where $L$ is the image of $\rho$.

1. check that the determinant is a group homomorphism;
2. now use the fact that the kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup of $L$;
3. the simplicity of $G$ implies that the kernel of $\det$ is $1$ or $L$;
4. the first isomorphism theorem, and the fact that $G$ is non-abelian imply that the kernel is equal to $L$.

The same argument works for the image of $\sigma$ and we have the required conclusion.